# How to implement std::optional's copy constructor?

Tags: c++, constexpr, boost-optional

I am implementing [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional), but have run into a snag with one of its [copy constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/optional).

Here is a sketch of my implementation:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
class optional
{
  public:
    constexpr optional()
      : m_is_engaged(false)
    {}

    constexpr optional(const optional &other)
      : m_is_engaged(false)
    {
      operator=(other);
    }

    constexpr optional &operator=(const optional &other)
    {
      if(other.m_is_engaged)
      {
        return operator=(*other);
      }
      else if(m_is_engaged)
      {
        // destroy the contained object
        (**this).~T();
        m_is_engaged = false;
      }

      return *this;
    }

    template<typename U>
    optional &operator=(U &&value)
    {
      if(m_is_engaged)
      {
        operator*() = value;
      }
      else
      {
        new(operator->()) T(value);
        m_is_engaged = true;
      }

      return *this;
    }

    T* operator->()
    {
      return reinterpret_cast<T*>(&m_data);
    }

    T &operator*()
    {
      return *operator->();
    }

  private:
    bool m_is_engaged;
    typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof(T),alignof(T)>::type m_data;
};

#include <tuple>

int main()
{
  optional<std::tuple<float, float, float>> opt;

  opt = std::make_tuple(1.f, 2.f, 3.f);

  return 0;
}
```

The problem is that the compiler complains that `optional`'s `constexpr` constructor does not have an empty body:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp 
test.cpp: In copy constructor ‘constexpr optional<T>::optional(const optional<T>&)’:
test.cpp:15:5: error: constexpr constructor does not have empty body
     }
     ^
```

I'm not sure how to initialize `optional::m_data` otherwise, and I haven't been able to find a reference implementation the web (`boost::optional` apparently does not use `constexpr`).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you notice in your link that the move and copy ctor are not marked `constexpr`?

Comment: Digging into the [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3672.html) they talk about it also: `It is still possible to make the destructor trivial for T's which provide a trivial destructor themselves, and we know an efficient implementation of such optional<T> with compile-time interface — **except for copy constructor and move constructor** — is possible.`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++11 functions and constructors marked as `constexpr` are very limited in what they can do. In the case of constructors, it cannot contain basically anything other than `static_assert`, `typedef` or *using declarations* or *using directives*, which rules out calling `operator=` inside the body of the constructor.