# std optional copy constructor

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm very confused about how `std::optional`'s copy constructor is supposed to be implemented to meet the requirements of being `constexpr`.

Note there are many other questions on Stackoverflow asking something similar, such as:

[How to implement std::optional's copy constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21248347/how-to-implement-stdoptionals-copy-constructor)

[std::optional implemented as union vs char[]/aligned_storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52338255/stdoptional-implemented-as-union-vs-char-aligned-storage)

However, neither of these questions are actually asking about the COPY CONSTRUCTOR.  I am specifically asking about the copy constructor, with a function signature (from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/optional) as follows:

```
constexpr optional( const optional& other );
```

Now, I've read enough about `std::optional` to know the basics.  A typical mistake implementors make is to try and implement it with `std::aligned_storage`.  Since placement new cannot work in a `constexpr` (at least in C++17), this won't work.  Instead, a union type needs to be used so it can be directly constructed.  Something like:

```
struct dummy_type {};

union optional_impl
{
  dummy_type m_dummy;
  T m_value;
};
```

Okay, but still... I *still* don't see how we are supposed to meet the requirements of implementing the copy constructor as `constexpr`.  The problem is that in the copy constructor, we need to check if `other.has_value()` is true.  If it is, we want to directly copy `*other`, otherwise we just want to initialize `m_dummy`.  But how can we express this conditional decision in a `constexpr` copy constructor?

```
constexpr optional( const optional& other ) : m_dummy{}
{
  if (other.has_value()) new (&m_value) T(*other); // Wrong! Can't use placement new
}
```

The only way I can see this working is using placement new.

So I checked some actual implemenations, like the gcc implementation here:

https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/optional#L248

And indeed... they just use placement new.  And in fact, the copy constructor isn't event `constexpr` (which I guess is a defect).

Here's another implementation:

https://github.com/akrzemi1/Optional/blob/master/optional.hpp#L416

And again, they just use placement new.

So how can `optional(const optional&)` ever be implemented as a `constexpr`?   Is this a defect in the standard or something?

Comment: Why do you have to check?  Can't you just copy `other`'s union to `this`'s?

Comment: But what if the union has a non-trivial copy constructor?

Comment: Oh yeah.  If you have a `std::string` as the member then there would be no copy constructor.

Comment: Note that `emplace` is not `constexpr`. I wouldn't expect the standard to require the copy constructor use only constexpr-friendly mechanisms to initialize the object while `emplace` doesn't have to when it's the same operation on the "actually need to do something" path. Therefore, I suspect `constexpr` would apply only to the case where the copied-from object is disengaged.

Comment: @chris You cannot change the active member of a union (in C++17) or placement-new a new object in a constant expressions, but you can initialize and copy a union with the implicitly defined copy constructor. So copy construction is possible in either case (if T is trivially copyable), but `emplace` is not.

Comment: @uneven_mark, Right, I was focusing on the non-trivially-copyable Ts per the above comments.

Comment: @chris Ah ok, but in that case it turns out that the standard specification gives no requirement on `constexpr`ness of the copy constructor at all: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/optional#ctor-6

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For C++17, see [optional.ctor]/6:

> ... If `is_trivially_copy_constructible_v<T>` is `true`, this constructor shall be a `constexpr` constructor.

In that case, the union will also be trivially copyable, so there is no problem.

In all other cases, the constructor will still carry the `constexpr` specifier even though it can't be used in a constant expression. This is ok: a function template (or member function of class template) is allowed to be declared `constexpr` as long as it has at least one possible instantiation that is usable in constant expressions. ([dcl.constexpr]/6)

In C++20, the wording has changed thanks to [P0602R4](http://wg21.link/P0602R4). However, I think that this did not change the `constexpr` requirements. If `T` is trivially copyable, then the constructor is trivial, which implies that it's also `constexpr`. If `T` is not trivially copyable, then the standard does not say the constructor must be usable in constant expressions, so there is no such requirement.

Comment: From which version of the standard is this citation from? Does not match the draft on [http://eel.is/c++draft/optional.ctor](http://eel.is/c++draft/optional.ctor).

Comment: @Holt The current one (C++17).

Comment: @Holt It surprises me that the current draft has different wording. I'll look into it.

Comment: @Holt C++20 allows `new` in constexpr functions so the wording most likely has changed.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica But only the global replaceable (allocating) allocation function may be used, so placement-new into allocated storage is still not possible. https://eel.is/c++draft/expr#const-4.17 How do you implement it with only that?

Comment: @uneven_mark Good call.  Not sure what changed to allow the change then.